# Populate a cell-based NSOutlineView whose cells have a title and an image

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview

I'm wondering if there is a way to use Cocoa bindings to populate a cell-based `NSOutineView` whose cells are `NSButtonCell` of a button type, with both images and titles.  So, one source of confusion is that I'm trying to provide 2 pieces of information for each cell, an image and a string.

The other thing that confuses me is that normally I think you'd populate a cell-based table by setting the `value` binding of the `NSTableColumn`.  But if the column's prototype cell is `NSButtonCell` of a style other than radio button or checkbox, then the `value` binding disappears.

Comment: @stevesliva:  Thanks, but the TableViewPlayground sample says that it is for a view-based table, and I asked about cell-based tables, so I'm not sure if the sample is applicable.

Comment: Ah, yes... facepalm.  Missed your focus here.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something that doesn't exactly answer the question I asked, but comes close enough for my purposes.  Instead of using `NSButtonCell`, I use `NSTextFieldCell`, and insert the image beside the text as an attachment within an attributed string.